# Where is the filesystem marked as "erroneous" with /etc/fstab errors=continue setting?

Tags: mount, fstab

From `man mount` errors=continue in /etc/fstab means:

> ignore errors and just mark the file system erroneous and continue

Where is the filesystem marked erroneous? I would like to set up an alert based on this (cron->email for example), but don't know what to check for the error state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [filesystem howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Filesystems-HOWTO-6.html):

> Ext2fs keeps track of the filesystem state. A special field in the
>   superblock is used by the kernel code to indicate the status of the
>   file system. When a filesystem is mounted in read/write mode, its
>   state is set to `Not Clean`. When it is unmounted or remounted in
>   read-only mode, its state is reset to `Clean`. At boot time, the
>   filesystem checker uses this information to decide if a filesystem
>   must be checked. The kernel code also records errors in this field.
>   When an inconsistency is detected by the kernel code, the filesystem
>   is marked as `Erroneous`.

So you're probably looking for device states that do not mention "clean", or otherwise match `grep -i error`; `dumpe2fs` should show the state.

```
$ dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda1 | grep state
dumpe2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
Filesystem state:         not clean
$
```